# PHPMailer - Error al incluir archivos

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un proyecto en marcha y estoy usando PHPMailer para el envio de mail para usuarios que se registren en mi plataforma.
Cuando el usuario se registra me aparece una serie de errores que no acabo de entender a pesar de que los haya buscado.
Este proyecto esta en su versión local, no está subido a producción pero uso un mail de un dominio al cual tengo acceso desde webmail.

Este es el código que estoy aplicando:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function enviarMail($remitente, $destinatario, $asunto, $html){
  include_once(FCPATH.'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
  include_once(FCPATH.'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
  //

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;//Testing
  $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.domain';
  $mail->Port = '587';
  $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';
  $mail->Password = 'secret';
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
  $mail->setFrom($remitente, 'Mailer');
  $mail->addAddress($destinatario);
  $mail->Subject = $asunto;
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Body = $html;
  //$mail->send();
  if(!$mail->Send()){
    //Mensaje no enviado
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
  //mensaje enviado

}
```

Y estos los errores que recibo:

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\proc\procedures_user.php on line
>   201
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\formulario_valida.php on line 178
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant FCPATH - assumed 'FCPATH' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 8
>
> Warning: include_once(FCPATHPHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 8
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'FCPATHPHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant FCPATH - assumed 'FCPATH' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 9
>
> Warning: include_once(FCPATHPHPMailer/src/SMTP.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 9
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'FCPATHPHPMailer/src/SMTP.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\includes\enviar_mail.php:12 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webs\cmedc\AVM2020\formulario_valida.php(221):
>   enviarMail('acreditacion@cm...', 'cristian@contex...', 'AVM2020 -
>   Confi...', '

¿Cómo podría resolver este problema o cual podría ser el fallo, teniendo en cuenta que tanto usuario y contraseña son correcto ya que he comprobado accediendo a dicha cuenta?

Comment: Has probado con un: require_once 'nombredelaclase.php'; Y verifica de llamar a la clase en todos los formularios que creas necesarios

Comment: Ahi te esta diciendo que no encuentra la clase

Comment: Tienes problemas con tus rutas. La mayoría de errores vienen, creo yo, porque no has incluido el archivo donde defines tu constante `FCPATH`. Como muchos otros elementos dependen de esa constante y no está en el contexto, ninguno de esos elementos va a funcionar. Determina donde defines esa constante e incluye ese archivo.

Comment: @francofernandez he probado de añadirlo como me has comentado quedando el código así: `require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

function enviarMail($remitente, $destinatario, $asunto, $html){  
  require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
  require_once 'class.smtp.php';` pero me lanza este error: **require_once(class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in** y también este ** require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')**

Comment: @A.Cedano he instalado PHPMailer mediante composer en mi carpeta del proyecto y en principio indicandole la ruta debería funcionar pero me saltan los errores comentados anteriormente...